# Virtual Device Configuration: "A system image must be selected to continue"

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have installed the newer Android Studio on my new Asus computer, but
when I try to run the emulator via the android virtual device manager
and create a virtual device, I get an error every time like this:

[image: Screen shot of AVD Manager Virtual Device Configuration screen]

Answer (score 39):

I had a similar problem.

1. Make sure you are connected to the internet.
2. When you select a System Image, press <kbd>enter</kbd> (click or double-click didn't work for me). Wait for Android Studio to download missing components.
3. Now, if you select the System Image, the "next" button will be active. Click on "next" to continue creating your virtual device.

Please note that the download could take a very long time. You may wish to try using HTTP by unchecking ***use secure connection***, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates -> *then click on "Use Secure Connection"*

Comment: So there is always some to be downloaded even if there's no link 'download'... "Select" means "press enter"...

Comment: "When you select a System Image, press enter click or double-click didn't work for me)" .... this is still true ... or at least it was for me.

Answer (score 14):

Click the download arrow  next to the system image of your choice, 
in my case, *Tiramisu* (API level 33).

This will start the download you want.

[image: 'A system image must be selected to continue.']

The system image is typically *1.4 GB*, so expect the download to take
several minutes.

When completed, the download arrow is gone, indicating that this
system image is "selected". 
And the <kbd>Next</kbd> button is now clickable.

[image: 'A system image has been "selected".']