# System image selection while create virtual device

Tags: android-studio

Trying to create virtual Android device. I have selected image, but Android Studio complains `A system image must be selected to continue` and not allows to press `Next` button. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual Device Configuration: "A system image must be selected to continue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118278/virtual-device-configuration-a-system-image-must-be-selected-to-continue)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by pressing **enter** button for the options that do not hold download button with it.

Not a single instruction was there for pressing "Enter" button :(